# install spark with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a virtual machine using VirtualBox, and then install Spark on the virtual Machine.

I created the Ubuntu machine using Cloudera's VM that made available for udacity.

After creating the virtual machine, VM is running perfect. I checked the java version, it is 1.6.

Then, I downloaded Spark and tried to run the pyshell, but following is the error give : [spark error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRUae.png)

I searched online for this error, and some people suggested that it might be because Java version, and I should use Java 1.7 for Spark. So, I tried to install Java 1.7, but following is the error I got:

[image: installing java error]

Does anyone know what is wrong with this ? If java is the real problem, how should i install the correct version of java ?

Thank you a lot ! I would really appreciate if someone can point out for me , thanks !

Comment: It says: `sudo: apt-get: command not found`, so you may not even have apt-get installed

Comment: how should I install apt-get ?

Comment: Show the error messages in the body of the question as text, not as links to screenshots.

Comment: `dpkg` is part of the `apt` package, which should be part of the initial Ubuntu installation. Is your `$PATH` messed up? This might be a better question for [ubuntu.se].

Comment: I checked the usr/bin and did not see apt-get, does this mean something corrupted while installing ? Or since I used the cloudera vm for training, do you think it has something to do with that ?

Comment: that because that not an ubuntu ! that's a centos.

Comment: Is @eliasah correct? Do you have a file `/etc/redhat-release`? If so, what's in it? If you're running CentOS, this question would be a better fit for [unix.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about installing packages, not about programming. Try [unix.se].

Answer (score 3):

Cloudera VMs aren't build on Ubuntu but CentOS. You need to use yum install to install packages.

Comment: Any suggestions on installing java 1.7 ?  Thanks :)

Comment: Usually it should be already installed on those VMs. It was the last time I've used one (2y ago).

Comment: @kashkalik if my answer solved your issue, please accept it to close the question.